# Header issues with a C static library wrapped distributed as a binary xcframework with Swift Package Manager

Tags: c, swift, header, xcframework

I have a large C++ / CMake code base, complete with a C API. I'm looking to wrap this as a pre-built binary xcframework, and delivered via a Swift package.

I have this working, along with a relatively permissive `modules.modulemap` file, but only in the case where I have curated the header files carefully to have `#include` directives pointing to other headers files in a *relative* manner.

The example `modules.modulemap` file:

```
framework module COOLKit {
  umbrella header "COOLKit.h"
  module * { export * }
  export *
}
```

An example of the `Headers` folder for this framework looks like the following, called `COOLKit`:

```
├── COOLKit.h
└── cool
    ├── additions.h
    ├── cpp.h
    ├── exported
    │   ├── callbacks.h
    │   ├── structs.h
    │   ├── results.h
    │   └── image.h
    └── cool.h
```

Each header file, if referring to another one, does so *relatively*, so e.g. `structs.h` may do the following

```
#include "../cpp.h"
```

Ordinarily, though, the original code has all been written in such a way that a common, root include path is specified, and the above should ideally just read

```
#include "cool/cpp.h"
```

… but this fails with SwiftPM when it emits the module during build: `'cool/cpp.h' file not found`

Specifying paths in terms of the root framework, does work:

```
#include <COOLKit/cool/cpp.h>
```

… however I'm keen to avoid this requirement, as changes to includes in the original C++ library would be extensive.

Is there a way forward where I can keep `#include` statements as is and work from the root of the `Headers` folder within the framework as the search path to work from?